# Write to CSV file Column by Column from For loop output

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to create a csv file as follows with 2 column headers as "Y1" and "Y2"

```
Y1 Y2 
i1 z1
i2 z2
i3 z3
```

The code I developed is as follows:

```py
with open(r"./file.csv", "a") as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1, delimiter="\t", lineterminator="\n")
    row = []
    row_1 = []
    for i in test_data["data"][1]:
        row.append(i)

    for z in test_results:
        row_1.append(z)

    writer.writerow([row, row_1])
```

I am only getting rows and not the i and z in a different columns. How can write to the csv and get the i and z next to each other in 2 different columns

Comment: So, are `test_data['data'][1]` and `test_results` the same size?  If so, you can just zip them.  I'll show in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The "zip" here combines the two lists, so that row is a 2-tuple with one column from each.  That's exactly what writerow wants.

```
with open(r'./file.csv','a') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    for row in zip(test_data['data'][1], test_results):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

You might even be able to do it in one shot:

```
with open(r'./file.csv','a') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    writer.writerows( zip(test_data['data'][1], test_results) )
```

Note "writerows" instead of "writerow".

Answer (score 0):

And please make sure that you adhere to the [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) format for CSV files.

It can save you a whole lot of heartache for many edge cases for data containing apostrophes, commas, and quotation marks.

Comment: How do you see OP not adhering to RFC-4180... they're using the csv module which is compliant, what's missing?

Comment: If its compliant then all good. I was just highlighting to ensure they are aware. Thanks for the update @ZachYoung

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the actual input data, or the actual output, what's going on.

I mocked up some input data like this to satisfy `for i in test_data["data"][1]`:

```py
test_data = {
    "data": [
        "foo",
        ["Y1", "i1", "i2", "i3"],
    ]
}
```

and `for z in test_results`:

```py
test_results = ["Y2", "z1", "z2", "z3"]
```

Now, when I run your code as-is, I get an output CSV that looks like:

```
['Y1', 'i1', 'i2', 'i3']    ['Y2', 'z1', 'z2', 'z3']
```

(I assume your header isn't in the actual input, but I included it just to make your small example code work.)

Following @Tim Roberts' suggestion, using `zip()` is probably the most correct way to join your two columns:

```py
rows = zip(test_data["data"][1], test_results)

print(list(rows))
```

and we can see that the values from data and results have been properly joined:

```py
[
    ("Y1", "Y2"),
    ("i1", "z1"),
    ("i2", "z2"),
    ("i3", "z3"),
]
```

From here, using the csv writer is just a few lines of code:

```py
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter="\t", lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

and I get:

```
Y1  Y2
i1  z1
i2  z2
i3  z3
```

To me, the most important concept to take away is get your data set up first (like we can see in that `print(list(rows))` statement), then do the CSV writing stuff.

Here's the complete program:

```py
import csv

test_data = {
    "data": [
        "foo",
        ["Y1", "i1", "i2", "i3"],
    ]
}

test_results = ["Y2", "z1", "z2", "z3"]

rows = zip(test_data["data"][1], test_results)

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter="\t", lineterminator="\n")
    # writer.writerow(["Y1", "Y2"])  # if you need to write your header manually
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

I also don't see a need to append: get your data composed and sorted, then just "write" to the CSV file, once.